# Aptana Studio 3 opens a copy of source while debugging

Tags: python, aptana-studio

While debugging a Python script, Aptana always opens a second window with my source code. If I edit this second file, and then go to my "original" file, it will ask me if I want to load the changes that were made on the file system. The original file has as path: "myproject/src/script.py" and the new created file has "C:\Users\Myself\aptana studio 3 workspace\myproject\src\script.py".

I want Aptana not to open this new file, as I'm used to in my other developing machine.

Any insights will be greatly appreciated.

This is in Win 8 Pro. Pydev 2.7